# Access a websocket using Java and print response

Tags: java, websocket

I have a websocket which I have tested by using Google Chrome.
My aim is to get the response from the websocket and print it by using Java.
I have already done so by using this piece of code on Chrome:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://address:port');
webSocket.onmessage = function(data) { console.log(data); }
```

This works really well, now I need to do the same but by using Java.
Any advice on how to to this?

Comment: Google "java websocket client"

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I most tutorials either let me build the websocket and then send a message and receive the output or they ask me to import external APIs.
My aim is to connect to the ws and get the output without sending a message. Moreover I can not import any jar file, the maximum I can do is to use maven and its dependencies

Comment: My best bet is that you did it wrong. You dont have to send anything in order to receive messages via ws (except handshakes and subscriptions). What do you mean by "importing external APIs" ????????? If you mean libraries then that is correct as I dont think that JDK has built in WS support.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a start

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

impl your client

```
private static class JavaWebSocketClient extends WebSocketClient {

 public JavaWebSocketClient(URI serverUri) {
    super(serverUri);        
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
    System.out.println("Connected");
    // do whatever        
 }

 @Override
 public void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("got: " + message);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    System.out.println("Disconnected");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

use your client

```
JavaWebSocketClient client = new JavaWebSocketClient(new URI(URL));    
client.connectBlocking();
```